# Append Array with UserDefaults input text

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have an Array of strings which is populating a collection view and that works well. The issue is I want to append that array with Strings that is saved in user defaults from user input textfield. I am getting the UserDefault data, The issue is it is not showing up in seperate collection view cell. it is getting attached at the end of each string in the current cells. Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

This is what I tried so far:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let value = defaults.string(forKey: "Gratitude")
    print(value!)
    //Array that I am trying to append with userdefault data       
    gratitudeArray.append(value!)

    // Configure the cell
    cell.cellLabel.text = gratitudeArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

// I am geeting user input from alert and saving in userdefaults like this:

func presentAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Create your own Gratitude:", preferredStyle: .alert)

```
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
            // store data
            UserDefaults.standard.set(field.text, forKey: "Gratitude")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } else {
            print()
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        //print(textField.text!)
        //textField.placeholder = ""
    }

    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: this is because you are appending the `gratitudeArray` elements in the same cell which you have already defined for storing the elements in the `collectionView`

Comment: do one thing whatever you are getting from the `UserDefaults`, do append it in the same array which you previously used to    populate your `collectionView` cells

Comment: What you want to display in cell? "gratitudeArray[indexPath.row] + value" or "gratitudeArray + value"

Comment: @ Samarth Kejriwal thanks for your reply and thats is what I am trying to do, but it is not showing in new cell in collection view. it's getting attached to the end of currrent cells

Comment: @ JD I want to display both gratitude and the value of userDefaults in seperate cells

Comment: Be clear with example. e.g. gratitudeArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and userDefault value is "0". Then how you want to display in collectionView? [10,20,30,40,50,60,70] or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0] or [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0]?

Comment: The second option [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0], thank you. I updated my question with how I am getting user input that might help.

Comment: then you need to append your userDefault data in confirmAction clouser and reload collectionView.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I do that? How would I add an array to hold user input text and save the array to user defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Store String in ViewDidLoad() like below:

```
var strValue: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    strValue= defaults.string(forKey: "Gratitude")
}
```

and display in cellForItemAt like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.cellLabel.text = gratitudeArray[indexPath.row] + " " + strValue
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am getting the same result. The append value is not showing in different/seperate cell, it is attached to the end of current cells.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want number of cells to increase by one (the value you extract out of UserDefaults). For that, you should append it some place which is outside collection view's data source methods (like viewDidLoad()) and then reload your collection view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    strValue = defaults.string(forKey: "Gratitude")
    gratitudeArray.append(strValue)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do and i used your suggestion, but it's only increasing by one cell. whenever I input more text into userdefaults it's replacing the text in current cell. instead of adding another cell to displaying the new data.

Comment: Could you provide more details like when/where are you capturing the data from user and when do you want it to reflect on UI as an additional field in your collectionview? 

If you are going back and forth from user input screen to collection view screen and want to persist every data that user enters, then instead of single string, you need to persist the whole array of strings in user defaults (or any persistence like sqllite). Each time user inputs, you append in the array, and persist the array. Then fetch the whole array from UserDefaults when you want to display it in collectionview

Comment: @ Vaidhav  Misra thanks for your response, I am using an alert textfield to get user input. I updated my question with the code.

Comment: Glad to help. The point is you need to add the append() call to your array after you get input from user. In your case that is probably in UIAlertAction 's completion block and call reloadData() on your collectionview after your append. Then you need to make sure the whole array is persisted in case it is released (like if view is popped) if you want updated array to be displayed next time your screen loads

Comment: The UIAlertAction is on a seperate ViewController, so I will have to create an array to hold user textInput and save that array to user defualt?

Comment: Right! I think then you can keep the append call in viewdidload of collectionview controller as before.

Comment: @ Vaibhav Misra yes I figured it out, I created an array to hold user input then save to user default. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating an array in my alert controller to hold user input and then save that array to user defaults.

func presentAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Create your own Gratitude:", preferredStyle: .alert)

```
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let field = alertController.textFields {

            let textFieldArray = field as [UITextField]
            let text = textFieldArray[0].text

            let key = "Gratitude"

            var myArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: key) ?? []
            myArray.append(String(describing: text!))
            UserDefaults.standard.set(myArray, forKey: key)

            print(myArray)


        } else {
            print()
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in

    }

    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```